# sqlalchemy で、Session に対して、 commit も rollback もしないで close した場合何がおこる？

Tags: sqlalchemy

いまいち、ドキュメントから見つけ出すことができないので質問しています。

#### Session に対して、 commit も rollback もしない状態で close すると何が起きますか？

- commit される？
- rollback される？
- もしくは、それ以外の何か？（もしそうならば、それは何？)

Comment: この記事 [How to close a SQLAlchemy session?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21738944/9014308) に情報がありそうです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it

^ の段落の中にある、 `session_scope` を使ってみた結果、 commit も rollback もしなければ、最後には勝手に rollback されていました。

なので、

- Answer: ロールバック

の様子です。